# How to use powershell to pull out of office from exchange calendars?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to get a supervisors direct reports form AD then use that information to pull each direct reports out of office out of exchange 2013.  Then mail this information everyday so the supervisor knows will be gone that day.  I pulled some of this script from here and it works great on one file at a time or I am not feeding it right.  Can anyone advise what I might be doing wrong and how to fix?  Thanks in advance.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Identity "supervisor" -Properties directreports |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty directreports |
Get-ADUser -Properties mail |
Select-Object mail

foreach ($user in $users)

{
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
    $version = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2
    $service = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($version)
    $service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    $service.AutodiscoverUrl($user)

    $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar, $user)
    $calendarFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.calendarFolder]::Bind($service, $folderid)
    $calendarView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView([System.DateTime]::Now, [System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(2))
    $calendarView.MaxItemsReturned = 200;
    $calendarView.PropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
    $result = $calendarFolder.FindAppointments($calendarView)
}

$result | format-table
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to get the out of office state for each direct report and or the out of office message you dont need to use exhange web services.  You can use the exchange management tools and use this:

```
get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration $emailAddressOrSamAccountName | select AutoReplyState,InternalMessage
```

This will give you the out of office state (whether the out of office message is enabled or not) and the internal out of office message set for the user. There are other properties you can grab too if you want. You can put that in your for each loop to get the status of each direct report.

Comment: Thanks but I need more information.  I need to pull when they will be out of the office.  Like if I leave today at 2:00 for a doctors appt that needs to show in the report that the supervisor receives in the morning.  This way the supervisor can tell when that day someone is leaving or when they are coming in with the report.

Comment: If you just do a get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration it does give you a property for start and end time as well as the out of office message and if its active or not. So if they set their out of office using only send during this time range then you will be able to get the time they will be out as well